# How do I make an UI-component in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates, haml

I have a few common UI-components, which varies only by content. Consider this example:

```
.component
    .top
        // a lot of component code

        .the_actual_top_content

        // some more component code
    .bottom
        // component code

        .the_actual_bottom_content

        // and more component code
```

I wonder is there any way to pass content blocks of haml code to function, which will wrap these blocks in my custom UI-component? Something like this:

```
= component
    <<
        .the_actual_top_content
    <<
        .the_actual_bottom_content
```

Or like this:

```
= render :layout => 'component' do
    = content_for :top do
        .the actual_top_content
    = content_for :bottom do
        .the_actualy_bottom_content
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is defining helper functions for your UI components. For example, create this helper method in `ApplicationHelper`:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def some_helper
    content_tag :div do
      yield
    end
  end
end
```

And then in your HAML template do this:

```
= some_helper do
  .the_actual_top_content
```

This will render:

```
<div class="ui">
  <div class="the_actual_top_content"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Edit**:

Found a better solution, use `render :layout`:

Here is a partial called `_ui.html.haml`:

```
.ui
  = yield
```

Which is called like this:

```
= render :layout => 'ui' do
  .the_actual_top_content
```

Which wil render the same HTML as above.

---

**Edit 2**
Although far from ideal, here is a way to do what you are asking:

Here is a partial called `_ui2.html.haml`:

```
.ui2
  .topcontent= top
  .bottomcontent= bottom
```

Which is called like this:

```
- top = capture do
  .something content on top
- bottom = capture do
  .something content on bottom
= render 'ui2', :top => top, :bottom => bottom
```

I've tried to place the `capture` blocks on the render line, but that doesn't work with properly with HAML indentation.

Comment: Thank you. Does it support more than one parameter? As you can see I need to pass at least two of them at the same time.

Comment: I would create two separate HAML partials (see my edit above), one for top content, and one for bottom content. Else, take a look at [`content_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for).

Comment: I would have to create at least three different files for one component. This will make developing even harder, because the same component would be spread across the files. I updated my question with a render-like example.

Comment: I've updated my answer with something you might use. Not ideal, but it works.

Comment: Thanks, this is certainly the solution. I will wait sometime in hope that someone came up with better one. Because these one pollutes global variables scope, which may lead to hard-to-find errors.